# How to use pywebview to open hyperlinks with target = "_blank" mark inside the window instead of using an external browser?

Tags: python, windows, webview, webview2, pywebview

[text](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/issues/342)
My system is windows 10 and I created a simple window using pywebview, but when I click on other hyperlinks within this window to jump, it opens using an external browser instead of completing the jump within the pywebview window. How do I make all hyperlinks jump within the window?

```
import webview


window = webview.create_window("Webview Browser", "https://www.google.com")
webview.start()
```

It seems that starting from version 2.0, pywebview defaults to all redirects being opened in an external browser. Is it possible to modify its py file to reverse this change?

Is there still a library similar to pywebview that allows me to complete most browser operations within a small window?

I tried to modify the copya.py file, but I am using version 4.4.1 and the code is completely different.